# #Error appearing in calculated field

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have created the following field to work out decimal age from a date of birth.

```
DECIMAL AGE: Round(((Now()-[tbl_Suspects]![DateOfBirth])/365.25),2)
```

It has always worked, however,access is now returning #Error for each person, I suspect because Suspects with no DoB have started to appear.  Can someone help as I've tried various things from using iif is null and Nz but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Always check for nulls when doing math. Try:

```
DECIMAL AGE: iif([tbl_Suspects]![DateOfBirth] is not null, Round(((Now()-[tbl_Suspects]![DateOfBirth])/365.25),2) , null)
```